# Leer varias variables de un archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.7

Tengo un archivo **archivo.txt** donde tengo varias strings con datos. La estructura de las strings es siempre igual, pero cambian los valores.
Cada STX01 es el inicio de una nueva línea en el atchivo.

Ejemplo de **archivo.txt**:

```
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1025309             SYNFQCTest_Quality_B                      SYNFFCA  SYNFPW2300SYNFP1k200        SYNFB10250SYNFW12300SYNFP2k100        SYNFB20100SYNFW22300SYNFP3k200        SYNFB30250SYNFW32300SYNFP4            SYNFB40000SYNFW40000SYNFP5            SYNFB50000SYNFW50000SYNFP6            SYNFB60000SYNFW60000SYNFP7            SYNFB70000SYNFW70000SYNFSI                                                            SYNOIN1SYNOKN1SYNOON19982010    SYNOCNMario Rossi              SYNOCR                         SYNOMP00SYNOMC0000SYNOMD                SYNOSR0001000SYNOCL4260SYNOSW0800SYNONO01SYNOST800                                                                                                                                                                                                     SYNOSG0032SYNOSS0825SYNOSP02SYNONM               SYNOSI                                                            SYNOIN2SYNOKN2SYNOON19982011    SYNOCNMario Rossi              SYNOCR                         SYNOMP00SYNOMC0000SYNOMD                SYNOSR0001200SYNOCL1025SYNOSW1400SYNONO01SYNOST600~3 200~3 600                                                                                                                                                                                         SYNOSG0032SYNOSS9090SYNOSP01SYNONM               SYNOSI                                                            SYNEOT18ETX
    STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1025824             SYNFQCTest_Quality_B                      SYNFFCA  SYNFPW2300SYNFP1k200        SYNFB10250SYNFW12300SYNFP2k100        SYNFB20100SYNFW22300SYNFP3k200        SYNFB30250SYNFW32300SYNFP4            SYNFB40000SYNFW40000SYNFP5            SYNFB50000SYNFW50000SYNFP6            SYNFB60000SYNFW60000SYNFP7            SYNFB70000SYNFW70000SYNFSI                                                            SYNOIN1SYNOKN1SYNOON19982010    SYNOCNMario Rossi              SYNOCR                         SYNOMP00SYNOMC0000SYNOMD                SYNOSR0001000SYNOCL4260SYNOSW0800SYNONO01SYNOST800                                                                                                                                                                                                     SYNOSG0032SYNOSS0825SYNOSP02SYNONM               SYNOSI                                                            SYNOIN2SYNOKN2SYNOON19982011    SYNOCNMario Rossi              SYNOCR                         SYNOMP00SYNOMC0000SYNOMD                SYNOSR0001200SYNOCL1025SYNOSW1400SYNONO01SYNOST600~3 200~3 600                                                                                                                                                                                         SYNOSG0032SYNOSS9090SYNOSP01SYNONM               SYNOSI                                                            SYNEOT18ETX
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es extraer los digitos que siguen al **FFN** de todas las líneas. Por ahora, lo que he conseguido es extraer el de la primera línea del archivo usando el siguiente código:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    for linea in f:
        fn = re.search(r"FFN(\d+)", linea)
        if fn:
            ffn = (fn.group(1))
```

Resultado:

```
1025309
```

Y lo que me gustaría obtener es lo siguiente:

```
1025309
1025824
```

Alguna idea de como hacer para que el código me lea todas las líneas y no solo la primera?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuantas lineas hay archivo.txt? Pareciera que es una sola línea muy larga. Si es ese el caso, el archivo no tiene segunda línea en realidad.

Comment: @CandidMoe El archivo tiene 2 líneas, pero puede llegar a tener 50 perfectamente. Cada STX01 es el inicio de una nueva línea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probe el programa agregando sólo una línea para imprimir el calce encontrado:

```
import re

with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    for linea in f:
        fn = re.search(r"FFN(\d+)", linea)
        if fn:
            ffn = (fn.group(1))
            print(ffn)
```

y funciona tal cual lo pides, produciendo

```
1025309
1025824
```

Por lo demás la lógica es correcta; nada que objetar ahí.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, para formular una pregunta relacionada con esta debería crear otra o editar esta?

Comment: @andyio. Correcto. Si no se arma una confusión que nadie entiende.