# Enviar variable con mas de un valor por socket

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esta pregunta tiene relación con otra pregunta que hice previamente:

[Leer varias variables de un archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/405390/leer-varias-variables-de-un-archivo)

En un txt tengo varias líneas con un identificador **ffn** el cual necesito enviarlo por socket a mi servidor. He conseguido imprimir por pantalla el valor de los dos **ffn** de mi archivo, pero cuando lo envío a mi servidor, lo que ocurre es que e solo le llega el primer valor.

archivo.txt:

```
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN112357            SYNFQCTest_Quality_B                      SYNFFCC  SYNFPW2300SYNFP1k200        SYNFB10250SYNFW12300SYNFP2k100        SYNFB20100SYNFW22300SYNFP3k200        SYNFB30250SYNFW32300SYNFP4            SYNFB40000SYNFW40000SYNFP5            SYNFB50000SYNFW50000SYNFP6            SYNFB60000SYNFW60000SYNFP7            SYNFB70000SYNFW70000SYNFSI                                                            SYNOIN1SYNOKN1SYNOON19982010    SYNOCNMario Rossi              SYNOCR                         SYNOMP00SYNOMC0000SYNOMD                SYNOSR0001000SYNOCL1025SYNOSW0800SYNONO01SYNOST800                                                                                                                                                                                                     SYNOSG0032SYNOSS2099SYNOSP02SYNONM               SYNOSI                                                            SYNOIN2SYNOKN2SYNOON19982011    SYNOCNMario Rossi              SYNOCR                         SYNOMP00SYNOMC0000SYNOMD                SYNOSR0001200SYNOCL1025SYNOSW1400SYNONO01SYNOST600~3 200~3 600                                                                                                                                                                                         SYNOSG0032SYNOSS9090SYNOSP01SYNONM               SYNOSI                                                            SYNEOT18ETX
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN112359            SYNFQCTest_Quality_B                      SYNFFCC  SYNFPW2300SYNFP1k200        SYNFB10250SYNFW12300SYNFP2k100        SYNFB20100SYNFW22300SYNFP3k200        SYNFB30250SYNFW32300SYNFP4            SYNFB40000SYNFW40000SYNFP5            SYNFB50000SYNFW50000SYNFP6            SYNFB60000SYNFW60000SYNFP7            SYNFB70000SYNFW70000SYNFSI                                                            SYNOIN1SYNOKN1SYNOON19982010    SYNOCNMario Rossi              SYNOCR                         SYNOMP00SYNOMC0000SYNOMD                SYNOSR0001000SYNOCL1025SYNOSW0800SYNONO01SYNOST800                                                                                                                                                                                                     SYNOSG0032SYNOSS2099SYNOSP02SYNONM               SYNOSI                                                            SYNOIN2SYNOKN2SYNOON19982011    SYNOCNMario Rossi              SYNOCR                         SYNOMP00SYNOMC0000SYNOMD                SYNOSR0001200SYNOCL1025SYNOSW1400SYNONO01SYNOST600~3 200~3 600                                                                                                                                                                                         SYNOSG0032SYNOSS9090SYNOSP01SYNONM               SYNOSI                                                            SYNEOT18ETX
```

**EDIT para hacer varias aclaraciones**

Código que ejecuta el cliente:

```
 with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    for linea in f:
       fn = re.search(r"FFN(\d+)", linea)
       if fn:
           ffn = (fn.group(1))
           a = ('FFN'+ffn)
           client.send(a.encode('utf-8'))
```

Lo que recibe mi server:

```
FFN112357
```

Si realizo un print localmente obtengo lo siguiente:

```
FFN112357
FFN112359
```

Lo que me gustaría que reciba el servidor a través del socket.

```
P1FFN112357 P2FFN112359
```

Y en caso de que hubiera mas FFN en mi TXT, se siguieran sumando P3, P4...

Comment: Hola @Juanjo, cierto, se había pegado mal el código, de todas formas lo he editado añadiendo información.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que tu servidor recibe solo uno? ¿De qué forma se está leyendo en el servidor? El protocolo TCP no tiene el concepto de "mensaje" sino que todos los mensajes que envíes se "concatenan" por así decir en un solo flujo y del otro lado, según el tamaño que pongas en el `recv()` y otros factores, puedes recibir sólo una parte de los bytes enviados (siendo necesarios más `recv()` para seguir recibiendo el resto). Una solución típica es cerrar el socket tras haber enviado todo, y del otro lado hacer `recv()` hasta recibir 0 bytes (marca de conexión cerrada)

Comment: @abulafia el server tiene configurado recv(4096), por lo que no debería tener problemas en recibirlo.

Comment: @andyo puede tener problemas igualmente porque aunque pida 4096 bytes, si en el momento de ejecutar ese `recv()` han llegado menos (por ejemplo, ha llegado sólo lo correspondiente al primer `send()`), retornará eso y el resto no se leerán hasta que no se haga otro `recv()`. Insisto en la necesidad de tener en el servidor un bucle de lectura, del que se saldría al recibir 0 bytes (lo que ocurriría cuando el cliente cierre el socket)

Comment: Te recomendaría serializar un Json y mandarlo mediante el Socket, al llegar los descerializar y lo asocias a una clase receptora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta basándome en el código de @abdulafia

Había que modificar el lado del server:

```
msg = b""  # Buffer de bytes recibidos
    while True:  # Bucle infinito del que saldremos al leer 0 bytes
        recibido = s_cliente.recv(4096)
        if len(recibido) == 0:
            break
        msg += recibido

    s_cliente.close()  # Cerrar comunicación

    print (msg.decode())
```

Lado del cliente también modificado:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    contador = 0
    for linea in f:
        fn = re.search(r"FFN(\d+)", linea)
        if fn:
            ffn = (fn.group(1))
            contador += 1
            a = "P{}FFN{}\n".format(contador, ffn)
            client.send(a.encode('utf-8'))
```

Resultado obtenido en el server:

```
P1FFN112357
P2FFN112359
```

Gracias a todos por la aportación!!

Comment: ¿En qué se diferencia tu código del que yo di? Salvo por el hecho de que en lugar de imprimir toda la cadena recibida yo la dividía en trozos, la parte que recibe me parece idéntica. O al menos no estoy viendo la diferencia...

Comment: Utilizando tu código el servidor no me funcionaba, le he quitado la parte de los trozos y me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 3):

### Lado cliente:

(es igual a tu código, pero añadiendo lo de P1, P2, etc.. así como un retorno de carro (`\n`) al final de cada envío, para que en el lado servidor puedan separarse)

```py
contador = 0
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    for linea in f:
       fn = re.search(r"FFN(\d+)", linea)
       if fn:
           ffn = (fn.group(1))
           contador += 1
           a = "P{}FFN{}\n".format(contador, ffn)
           client.send(a.encode('utf-8'))

client.close()  # Se cierra el socket para indicar que ya no hay más datos
```

### Lado servidor

Es necesario que el servidor tenga también un bucle de lectura. Normalmente cabría esperar que en cada iteración de lectura se recibiera un "mensaje" de los enviados por el cliente, pero esto no está garantizado. El protoclo TCP crea un "tubo" por así decir que une al que envía con el que recibe, pero no hay mensajes "delimitados" dentro de ese tubo. Sólo bytes indiferenciados, por lo que es posible que en cada `recv()` recibas diferentes partes de lo que el cliente envió (eso sí, todas en el mismo orden).

Por tanto la estrategia más robusta es iterar en el servidor hasta que se detecte el cierre del socket (lo que se detecta cuando la cadena recibida tiene longitud cero). Lo que se va recibiendo se puede ir acumulando en un buffer de bytes, para después concatenarlo todo en una sola cadena que se puede decodificar y dividir por los `\n` para obtener cada mensaje individual.

```
# creación del socket pasivo
# aceptar al cliente
#
# Supongamos que el socket de lectura está en la variable `s_cliente`

msg = b""    # Buffer de bytes recibidos
while True:  # Bucle infinito del que saldremos al leer 0 bytes
  recibido = s_cliente.recv(4096)
  if len(recibido) == 0:
      break
  msg += recibido

s_cliente.close()  # Cerrar comunicación

# Al salir del bucle tenemos en `msg` todo pegado lo que el cliente envió
mensaje = msg.decode(msg, "utf-8")
trozos = mensaje.split("\n")

for trozo in trozos:
   print(trozo)
```

Comment: he modificado tu código de servidor un poco ya que al recibir datos del cliente dejaba de funcionar y ahora he obtenido lo que quería.

Comment: Un problema similar ocurre con send en el sentido de que no se garantiza el envío de la información en una sola llamada al método, basta con utilizar sendall para corregir este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

El código está bien en lo fundamental; sólo añadí un contador y optimize algunas partes.

Cambie el grupo de captura a `(FFN\d+)` para evitar tener que reinsertar `FFN`en la salida.

Para armar cadenas, creo que usar f-strings es más corto y sencillo que estar concatenando pedacitos. Además, puedes usar una expresión dentro de un f-string. Para separar cada valor, también agregue un `" "` al final del f-string.

Use `print` en lugar de `client.send` dado que no tengo un cliente/servidor para las pruebas, y en todo caso, el efecto es el mismo. El `print` va con `end=""` para no agregar un `\n` tras cada valor, igualando el comportamiento de `send()`.

```
import re

with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    secuencia = 0
    for linea in f:
        fn = re.search(r"(FFN\d+)", linea)
        if fn:
            secuencia += 1
            a = f"P{secuencia}{fn.group(1)} "
            # client.send(a.encode('utf-8'))
            print(a.encode('utf-8'), end="")
```

produce:

```
b'P1FFN1025309 'b'P2FFN1025824 '
```

Comment: sigue llegando solo el primer valor al servidor (P1)

Comment: @andyio. Publica el código del servidor para analizar la causa. Completa el código del cliente, para ver como establece la conexión.